# Paging table displayed with FileToMemoryTable

Tags: mobile, windev

Our project for Database Management need new feature that is paging (Display table throught selected page) for table. is anyone have knowlage about it, for reminder our table is displayed with BuildBrowsingTable and FileToMemoryTable. We are a bit confused how to do this with table displayed with FileToMemoryTable, because the table is automaticly fill by it self with the data on datafile.

Best Regard
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

When managing the table via browser the ideal thing to do is to manually manage the pagination. If I have not misunderstood the request .. Tables via browser are not recommended for managing a lot of data due to the high memory consumption of the client. Preferable to use table ajax mode on